# Derivation of the average perturbation as function of time

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm reading a book on molecular simulations (Understanding Molecular Simluations, D. Frenkel and B. Smit) and I'm reading derivation of the average perturbation response of an observable $A$ as a function of time, after having applied a perturbation.
This is what is written:

> Next, we consider a simple time-dependent perturbation. We begin by preparing
> the system in the presence of a very weak, constant perturbation (λB). The static
> response of A to this perturbation is given by Eq. (2.5.3). At time $t = 0$, we
> switch off the external perturbation. The response $\Delta$A will now decay to 0. We
> can write an expression for the average of $\Delta$A at time t :
> $$\left<\Delta A(t)\right>=\frac{\int d\Gamma exp([-\beta(H_0-\lambda B)]A(t))}{\int d\Gamma exp([-\beta(H_0-\lambda B)]}$$

where $d\Gamma$ runs over all the phase space, $\beta=(k_BT)^{-1}$, $H_0$ is the unperturbed hamiltonian, $\lambda$ is the perturbation, $B$ is che conjugate observable and equation 2.5.3 is:

> $$\left(\frac{\partial\left<\Delta A\right>}{\partial\lambda}\right)_{\lambda=0}=\beta\left(\left<AB\right>_0-\left<A\right>_0\left<B\right>_0\right)$$

where the $\left<...\right>_0$ stands for the ensemble average according to the unperturbed hamiltonian.

It continues from the definition of $\left<\Delta A(t)\right>$ as follows:

> where A(t) is the value of A at time $t$ if the system started at point $\Gamma$ in phase
> space and then evolved according to the natural time evolution of the unperturbed
> system. For convenience, we have assumed that the average of A in the
> unperturbed system vanishes. In the limit λ→0, we can write
> $$\left<\Delta A(t)\right> = \beta\lambda\frac{\int d\Gamma exp[-\beta H_0]BA(t)}{\int d\Gamma exp[-\beta H_0]}=\beta\lambda\left<B(0)A(t)\right>$$

I have several questions about this.

1. When it talks about switching off the perturbation, is it referring to the perturbation $\lambda$ or to another which is not shown here, something like $F(t)$?
2. If it's referring to $\lambda$, then why is it using the distribution according to the perturbed hamiltonian? At $t\neq0$ shouldn't the perturbation be off and the hamiltonian back to $H_0$?
3. If it's **not** referring to $\lambda$, which I assume then to be a constant perturbation, why isn't $B$ dependent on time? Moreover, it starts being independent, but then there it gets $B(0)$. I don't get why. To me it would make more sense if it had dependence on $t$, because what we are trying to compute is the average response at time $t$, so I should average over the phase space at time $t$, and the value of the observable $B$ for each state of the phase space $\Gamma$ depends on the fact that we had a perturbation. What I would write is more like:
   $$\left<\Delta A(t)\right> = \beta\lambda\frac{\int d\Gamma exp[-\beta H_0]B(t)A(t)}{\int d\Gamma exp[-\beta H_0]}=\beta\lambda\left<B(t)A(t)\right>$$

Why isn't it so? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood it. Basically we can consider $A(t)$ as a new observable, that is the property associated to it at time $t$. If we set ourselves in t=0, we can imagine to be looking for this observable, so the property in the future (for a moment we can assume we are able to know the future property values, but time correlation functions will take care of this). At the moment ($t=0$) our phase space is still defined by the perturbed hamiltonian $H=H_0-\lambda B$ so as if we were looking for any observable O, we compute the average of the operator $\Delta A(t)$ or equivalently $A(t)$. And to do so, we can integrate or we can use eq. 2.5.3 (with vanishing average of $A$) by using the current $B$, because it defines the current phase space. That's why we don't write $B(t)$ but rather $B(0)$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).